# app.config file becomes blank or corrupted after abrupt power loss

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

I have a WPF app, but this issue happened also with a console app. If the app is running and there's an abrupt power loss, the app.config file becomes blank or filled with several white spaces, making my app crash on boot.

I made a workaround by creating a task that replaces app.config file on boot with a backup app.config...but I store some keys in this app.config and this workaround makes me lose all my configuration.

What makes app.config go blank? is there a way to prevent this issue? or is there a way to prevent my app to crash if there's no app.config?

Thanks

Comment: That's odd. Does the same thing happen if you just kill the process?

Comment: i thought app.config is readonly. are you modifying it?

Comment: @stuartd no, if I kill the process everything works.

Comment: @Steve App.config is not readonly, in some apps I store keyvalue pairs for simple configuration persistence, but this happens even if I don't modify app.config at all.

Comment: usually you do that in settings

Comment: I've always used `<appSettings>` inside `app.config` by calling `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]`

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: no, @sql_dru I can't even recall I had this issue...its been a while already